# mapper.writeValueAsString(objectMap) cant process special character like á

Tags: java, objectmapper

```
String request = "{\"remarks\":\"á\",\"displayName\":\"my application\",\"apps\":\"check\"}";

List<LinkedHashMap> test = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getBytes(), List.class);
mapper.writeValueAsString(test);
```

Letter `á` is a special character can't process by `mapper.writeValueAsString(test);`

I've tried to deserialize but still converting to some other content [image]

Comment: Where `"remarks":"xE1"` is coming from (there's no property `remarks` is the sample data) ? The code you've shared would raise an **exception** because the input is **not** a JSON-array, but the question has no mention of it (but it should). Why are you creating `ObjectMapper` twice? Please fix the question, also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: What happens with `List<LinkedHashMap> test = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request, List.class);` ?

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the sample data you've shared can't be successfully deserialized and produce the output you've posted.